# Strict Transport Security configured but doesn't work for asp .NET core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, hsts

I have an .net core 2.2 application that comes with default Hsts enabled.

My config in startup is like this:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     .
     .
     .
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.MaxAge = currentDate.AddYears(1) - currentDate;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        });

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
        });
     .
     .
     .
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider 
    services)
    {
     .
     .
     .
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I have all this but when I check out my responses headers I see

```
Strict-Transport-Security : disabled
```

Comment: The application is deployed on EC2 AWS virtual machine so I'm not checking it on local